# API request from python not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an internal website URL has an api which gives response on browser and postman. But, when i try the same from python using requests module 
(No authentication enabled for the API)

code:

```
import requests
url = "http://internalsite/api/controller/method/param1=val1&param2=val"
res = requests.get(url)
```

res.text gives the following.

```
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Typ
e" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>\r\n<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>\r\n<style type="text/css">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-
family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\
nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555
;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id="h
eader"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id="content">\r\n <div class="content-container"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do no
t have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Please advice on the error details. Thanks

Comment: Check what headers are sent from the browser and try setting them on the Python request as well. Also, are you sure you don't have a session saved in your browser? Maybe you have a cookie already set.

Comment: "No authentication enabled for the API" The error message you are getting clearly suggests the opposite.

Comment: Your browser session may already be authenticated, which would explain why you're not currently seeing a auth prompt. Try opening a new session using Chrome's Incognito (or a different browser). The problem most likely lies with the internal server, as it's probably configured to require authentication, which you seem to not be aware of.

Comment: It is not a problem with seesion/cache. I have tried in incognito and another system. The browser gives the response without any issues.

Comment: @DirtyPenguin "The problem most likely lies with the internal server, as it's probably configured to require authentication, which you seem to not be aware of" It's not a problem, it is something that OPs code should take into account.

Comment: Chances are the site is using passthrough kerberos auth so you don't see it when using the browser, the browser just passes it through. There is, to my knowledge, no way of getting a 401 response without you actually being disallowed a resource due to credentials.

Comment: @HarishKothuri Don't post code/data in comments - edit it into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

It was a restriction from the intranet. Have tried in the system where there are no restrictions and works just like that. Thanks